# Postgres SQL Restore Permission denied to create and alter database

Tags: postgresql, mayanedms

I had a backup of my Mayan-EDMS database which is stored in file.sql. I am trying to restore it. While I am restoring the database using
 `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U mayan -d mayan -W -f file.sql` I got error that saying `psql:file.sql:23: ERROR:  permission denied to create database`. How to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the role `mayan`:

```
ALTER ROLE mayan CREATEDB;
```

Then it can create a database. Perhaps other aspects of restoring the database, like creating an extension, will require still higher privileges.

Comment: Thank you very much by the guidence by you alternig the role to superuser now I am able to bypass the error. Now I am getting error  saying database "mayan" already exists. Is superuser cant replace database?

Comment: Sure, a superuser can do anything. If that is a `pg_dump` you are restoring, create it with `--create --clean`, then it will contain a `DROP DATABASE` statement. Otherwise, add the `DROP DATABASE` to the script manually.